# Clear copy of current file from data

Tags: vba, excel, copy

There is workflow to fill in a sheet and mail it when you're done. The method to mail will send the current sheet as attachment, but it should directly create a new copy of the sheet where all your data is removed from.

I can clear the current sheet, but that's wrong, as I need to clear the *new* sheet. I have read about running macros on other workbooks, but it fails to run the macro. What's the best solution?

```
Sub SendData_Click()
    If MsgBox("Sure to send?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
        ' Save current sheet
        ActiveWorkbook.Save

        ' Send the current file
        Mail_ActiveSheet

        ' Mark this sheet as sent
        Worksheets("Data").Range("B6").Value = True

        ' Create a new emptied version
        Create_New_Copy

        MsgBox "Your data is sent"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Create_New_Copy()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FilePath As String

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    NewFileName = "FileNameHere " & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Now), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(Wb.Name, Len(Wb.Name) - InStrRev(Wb.Name, ".", , 1)))
    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewFileName & FileExtStr

    ' # This is the problem, how to clear only the new file??
    ' Clear_Sheet_Invoices

    ' Save this sheet as the new file
    Wb.SaveCopyAs FilePath
End Sub

Sub Clear_Sheet_Invoices()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Worksheets("MyDataSheet")

    ' Remove all contents
    Ws.Range("B2:F999").ClearContents

    ' Mark the "sent" flag for the new sheet to False
    Worksheets("Data").Range("B6").Value = False
End Sub
```

As you might note, I am using `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs` to create a copy, and I have a Sub `Clear_Sheet_Invoices` which can clear all required data. How to run this sub on the new file?

I have thought to copy the `MyDataSheet` to a new sheet, clear the data sheet, save the new file and copy the sheet back. On opening a file, I check if a copy of the sheet is present and I will remove the sheet. Yeah, damn ugly, there should be a better way right? ;)

Comment: Is the problem that it closes before you can clear it? Or that you can't target it from the current book? You may need to use the macro to call a macro in it to clear it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the definition of `Clear_Sheet_Invoices()` in that way that it requires a parameter of `Workbook` type and it would clear worksheet "MyDataSheet" in this workbook.

Then you can invoke this sub and pass the newly created workbook as a parameter.

Below is the code you need to change to implement it:

```
Sub Clear_Sheet_Invoices(Wb As Workbook)
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("MyDataSheet")

    ' Remove all contents
    Ws.Range("B2:F999").ClearContents

    ' Mark the "sent" flag for the new sheet to False
    Wb.Worksheets("Data").Range("B6").Value = False

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Create_New_Copy()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim NewWb As Workbook
    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FilePath As String

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    NewFileName = "FileNameHere " & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Now), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(Wb.Name, Len(Wb.Name) - InStrRev(Wb.Name, ".", , 1)))
    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewFileName & FileExtStr

    ' Save this sheet as the new file
    Wb.SaveCopyAs FilePath
    Set NewWb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)


    ' # This is the problem, how to clear only the new file??
    Call Clear_Sheet_Invoices(NewWb)
    Call NewWb.Close(True)

End Sub
```

---

Method `SendData_Click` doesn't require any changes.

Comment: thanks for the extreme fast response. However, this clears the *current* file and not the *new* file. Actually I have thought about this and perhaps it isn't the wrong idea: keep the current file the "input" (clearing it every time) and store "backups" (with the data intact).

Comment: @JurianSluiman I have fixed it. I passed reference to the original workbook instead of the new one into the sub `Clear_Sheet_Invoices`. It should work properly now.